# Why won't my IAM role show up when I'm trying to connect the Windows server to the Simple AD?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

During the AWS creation wizard I get this:

[image]

I've created an AMI role which should have the appropriate roles:

[image]

But the IAM role doesn't show up? What step have I overlooked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had created a role for the directory service instead of for EC2. The trust relationship should look like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```